# what happens if I call 2 functions inside a single script tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code :

```js
        <script>
             function handleClick(){
                document.body.style.color = "blue";
            }
            const secondButton = document.getElementById('second');
            secondButton.onclick = handleClick;
    
            function handleClick(){
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "tomato";
            }
            const thirdButton = document.getElementById('three');
            thirdButton.onclick = handleClick;
        </script>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Add Event Handler</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 onclick="console.log('hero programmer')">event handler</h1>
        <button onmouseout="handleClick()">click me</button>
        <button id="second">click me-1</button>
        <button id="three">click me-2</button>
        <button>click me-3</button>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

what i want is that when I click on the second button the text color will be blue & the background color of the full page will be tomato when I click on the third button. But upon clicking the second & third buttons the result is the same! The background color becomes tomato but the text color doesn't change to blue. Why is it so? What can I do get my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

you're redefining your function by using the same name. Try using different functions or just use an anonymous function if it's not being used elsehwere like:

```js
const thirdButton = document.getElementById('three');
thirdButton.onclick = function(){
    // do something.
};
```